# Interlocked FIFO Lists?

Tags: c, winapi, synchronization, queue, atomic

I see that I can create an Atomic FILO (First In Last Out) list with InterlockedPushEntrySList / InterlockedPopEntrySList. Is there an equivalent for a simple FIFO (First In First Out) list or queue as well? There appears to be in Kernel Mode but not for User Mode. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There (afaik) is not.  The SList synchronization objects are based on a singly-linked list, and you need a doubly-linked list to do FIFO.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I figured.

Answer (score 3):

Can confirm John's answer, there is no lock-free queue API available. If you're using VC++, you can use PPL's [concurrent_queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355358.aspx) class -- it's not lock-free (or at least, the last version I looked at wasn't), but it is high-perf and scalable.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement a queue as a singly linked list but then you need a head and a tail pointer - synchronising those with the element's next pointers is where the lock/spin free challenge comes in..